# tshark, listen to port does not work

Tags: ethernet, wireshark

How to listen to the port?
Just connect to host (IP, e.g google.com):

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -H IP  // not working
sudo tshark -i eth0 -H "IP"  // not working
sudo tshark -i eth0 host IP  // not working
```

And port:

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 host IP and port 80 // not working
```

Answer (score 1):

-H is to specify a host file in a format similar to your system's /etc/hosts file.

If that isn't what you're attempting to use, look into -f flag.  This allows you to use a tcpdump style pre or post filter - depending on where it is placed.

Here are a few examples:

```
tshark -f "host 192.168.1.1" -i eth0 -w outputfile.pcap
tshark -i eth0 -f "host 192.168.1.1" -w outputfile.pcap

dumpcap -f "host 192.168.1.1" -i eth0 -w outputfile.pcap
dumpcap -i eth0 -f "host 192.168.1.1" -w outputfile.pcap

tcpdump -i eth0 "host 192.168.1.1 and port 80" -w outputfile.pcap
```

Also, depending on how much traffic your box is seeing, you might look into dumpcap or tcpdump.